# Eclipse Egit will not import repo in workspace

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am trying to import an existing git repository as an eclipse project. The repository is stored in the location ~/src/repo_dir, and ~/src/ is my eclipse workspace directory.

If I use the sequence of menu operations:

```
File --> Import --> Git --> Projects from Git --> Local --> (Select my repo) 
--> "Import as General Project"
```

I get the error:

```
/Users/me/src/repo_dir overlaps the location of another project: 'repo_dir'
```

and I can't import the project. It seems to be because Egit does not want the original repo that is being imported to already be in the workspace. However, if I then move the repo_dir out of the workspace directory ~/src/, and then import the project via the method above, it doesn't copy the contents to the workspace directory, so now my files live somewhere else, which is undesirable. The only workaround that I have found is to move the repo out of ~/src, import it, delete the resulting project, move the repo back into ~/src, and then import it with git as an 'Existing project.' Does anyone know of a cleaner way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different issues here:

1. Git handles a selected folder in your computer as a repository - and also stores some git-related metadata in it.
2. Eclipse handles a selected folder in your computer as your workspace. It stores that Eclipse configuration files (not meant to be shared), and even worse, it expects a single-level folder hierarchy for projects.

This means, putting a Git repository inside the workspace might cause a lot of unwanted issues - so I do not recommend this way (even if by some hack it is workable). However, if you want to organize all stuff related to an Eclipse workspace, you could create a folder structure as this:

- eclipse-stuff

  - workspace
  - git

    - git-repo1
    - git-repo2

The *workspace* folder is given to Eclipse as the workspace folder, while *git-repo1* and *git-repo2* are your Git repositories.

On the other hand, I like to put all my git repositories into a common folder, regardless of the Eclipse workspace I use them in, but if you want to organize contents, this might not be enough for you.

Comment: So in essence you are recommending the approach of storing only metadata within the eclipse workspace directory tree, while the source lives elsewhere? Is there a way to make this the default behavior for projects created within the eclipse interface, rather than imported as external repositories?

Comment: Basically, yes, you understood me correctly. But I do not know any easy way to store all projects outside the workspace (it can be set when the project is created either as a checkout or in the New project wizard), but the default setting is the workspace. That is why I suggested the workspace-specific git repositories - in that case, at least you handle all your stuff together - SVN/unversioned proejcts in the workspace, git projects next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with Eclipse Kepler.

End up with installing Eclipse Mars and import the new project in another workspace.(Luna will also work fine)

If you need to work on current projects and set up environment for the coming one...